# does GUI mean the same as MMI?

Tags: user-interface

any material on the core differences between the terms will be welcomed.

Comment: another similar term is HMI (human machine interface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By MMI, I assume you mean Man-Machine Interface.  If that's the case, then a Graphical User Interface (GUI) is just one *kind* of MMI, and the terms are not synonymous.  An MMI can be any kind of [user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) at all.

Answer (score 1):

GUI = Graphical User Interface. The graphical component is not necessarily present in MMI = Man-Machine Interaction (keyboard for example).

Answer (score 1):

**GUI**: Graphical User Interface, **MMI**: Man Machine Interface

While a GUI is about the interaction between people and machines via dynamic visual ways, MMI generally is about any sort of interaction between humans and machines. So GUIs are just a specialized portion of MMIs.

Answer (score 0):

**Graphic User Interface** and **Multi Media Interface**? if i am correct then its just terms, one does not exist with out another. You need graphics to represent buttons and buttons to execute the intended actions. But the MMI specifically talks about single interface that corresponds with multiple devices/software packages.

Comment: so if you talking about man machine interface/interaction then disregard this : )